# Could new users get "Beta" badge?

Tags: support, badges

Today I was looking over the badges page for the badges that I could (maybe one day) get. I noticed that "Beta" badge (that is acquired by users that participated on the beta phase of superuser) could be a badge that I would never get because I didn't even  know that Stack Exchange existed on the time of Super Users's beta.

So, there is a way for relatively "new" users to achieve this badge?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is not a change to get the beta badge in retrospect of the beta. However, plenty of SE websites are currently in beta or about to go into beta. (Check the list at [Area 51 SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)) You could participate in any of those to get the Beta badge there.

Comment: Correct. There is no way to achieve this badge unless you were there from the beginning and met the requirements at the time of beta.

Comment: Haha.  If you could get the Beta badge outside of the Beta, sort of defeats the whole purpose of having a badge.